# How do I nest multiple templates while keeping a wrapper for some pages

Tags: templating

I'm trying to figure out how to nest 3 templates and have them inherit the blocks. How can I sometimes reference the child.html when I need a wrapper and sometimes not reference it. Maybe I'm trying to do this the wrong way? Thank you for your feedback.

parent.html

```
{% block contentBlock %}
{% endblock %}
```

child.html

```
<div>    
{% extends "parent" %}
{% block content %}
</div>
```

child-child.html

```
{% extends "child" %}
{{ title }}
```

child2.html

```
{% extends "parent.html" %}
{% block contentBlock %}
{{ title }}
```

Comment: Check out Twig's 'use' inheritance, it might be what you are looking for: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this is the type of situation where you may want to consider having a second layout rather than opting for a more complicated inheritance scheme. If your layouts are somewhat complex and you want to keep your markup DRY I would suggest moving the more complex components of your layout into includes.

Also, when I get beyond the Layout » Template relationship, instead of defining blocks and extending the Template I opt for includes there as well. This makes my workflow efficient because I always consider the Template to be the base point, inheriting up into the Layout and inheriting down into any includes.

layout_1col.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% include 'head' %}
<body>
  {% include 'header' %}
  <main>
    {% block 'main' %}{% endblock %}
  </main>
  {% include 'footer' %}
</body>
</html>
```

layout_2col.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% include 'head' %}
<body>
  {% include 'header' %}
  <main>
    {% block 'main' %}{% endblock %}
  </main>
  <aside>
    {% block 'sidebar' %}{% endblock %}
  </aside>
  {% include 'footer' %}
</body>
```

MyTemplate.html

```
{% extends 'layout_1col' %}
{% block 'main' %}
  <p>My content</p>
  {% include 'mywidget' %}
{% endblock %}
```

By letting your layouts rely heavily on includes you can let them vary only where needed but keeping your inheritance logic simple and easily extended.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thanks for your feedback Michael.